# Accessing a member of a structure in an array of structures which is a member of an array of different structures

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, struct, lvalue

I have a structure called Object defined as:

```
    struct Object
    {
        char name[20];
        char description[50];
    };
```

I also have another structure called Room defined as:

```
    struct Room
    {
        int number;
        char description[50];
        struct Object objects[10];
    };
```

I then initialise an array of Room and attempt to change the name of an object in a room:

```
    void main()
    {
        struct Room rooms[1][1];
        rooms[0][0].objects[0].name = "Cabinet";
    }
```

The problem I have is that visual studio gives me these errors:

```
    rooms[0][0].objects[0].name = "cabinet";

    Error1:
        expression must be a modifiable lvalue

    Error2:
        '=': left operand must be l-value
```

I am using visual studio 2015 community edition's C++ compiler to compile and run C code.

I'm not sure if what i'm trying to do is possible in C, the idea is that i have 4 rooms, each room has 11 objects and each object can have a name and a description.

Paste bin to the full code http://pastebin.com/jQJekLk9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use simple assignment with strings.  You need to use `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(rooms[0][0].objects[0].name, "Cabinet");
```

Comment: More precisely, you cannot use simple assignment with *arrays*, including arrays of `char`.  You *can* use it with strings in the sense of pointers to `char`, though you do need to understand what it means when you do so.

Comment: Thank you so much, iv'e been trying to figure out what I did wrong for a good couple of hours now, I cant believe I forgot that I had to use strcpy even though I used it literally the line above in my full code.